# Flash Input Field - Can't Type

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am trying to edit an old flash file (cs4) that has an input box, at the moment the current .swf works ok and you can type.

As soon as I open the file and try and test the movie input field is locked and I can't edit it...

here is the action script code:

```
var senderLoad:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var receiveLoad:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

input1.setStyle("color","white");
input1.setStyle("fontFamily", "Arial");
input1.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
input1.setStyle("fontSize", "15");
input1.setStyle("borderStyle", "none");
input1.setStyle("borderColor", "white");
input1.setStyle("backgroundColor", "white");


receiveLoad.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
result1.text = receiveLoad.result1;
}

submit.onRelease = function() {

if (input1.text eq ""  ) {
    error.text="please enter some info";
} else 
{
getURL("http://mydomainname.co.uk/reg="+input1.text,"_self");
}
}
```

If anyone can help it would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be an issue with how the Arial font is embedded.

You could try setting the input1 TextField to "use device font"* in the .fla in Flash CS4 IDE, and see if you are allowed to enter text then. Using device font instead of embedding it may cause other issues, but it will let you see if the problem is related to font embedding, and set up proper embedding if needed.

Also, you should probably change `if (input1.text eq ""  )` to `if(input1.text == "")`, eq is deprecated.

Another thing that seems a bit strange is using white as both `color` and `backgroundColor`, sounds like it could give white text on a white background.

*: *I don't have access to a Flash CS IDE now, so I'm not sure of the steps and exact terminology, but the idea is to use use the Arial installed on the end users "devise" instead of embedding Arial in the swf.*

Comment: Thanks Lars - I'll give it ago tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Lars, I done that but it still doesn't work correclty for some reason... I have a masked field that sits over the top of the input box.

Have you got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case:

> Users cannot enter text in text input fields while in full-screen mode. All keyboard input and key-related ActionScript is disabled while in full-screen mode, with the exception of the keyboard shortcuts that take the viewer out of full-screen mode.

(taken from [Adobe Developer Connection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html))

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for developers who want to make full screen application in flash CS5 but also want to use input text field.

Keyboard entry is disabled in flash CS5 full Screen mode. You can find the solution [here](http://www.encompass-client.com/solution/flashhelp.html).